# Polymer 1.0 :Nested dom-repeat templates cannot show the content of a child object

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

I want to display an object content(comments)  in a post data (using firebase-collection)  : 
Here is the structure of a post in firebase :

```
"Publication" : {
       "date":"22-06-2015",
 "content" : "post example",
 "comments": {
  //a post has too many comments on it
  }
}
```

My goal is to add another dom-repeat to show comments but i cannot see anything.
Here is the code example(the first template work correctly as i mentioned)

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{posts}}" as="post">
      <!-- Content here is appearing correctly --> 
          <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{post.comments}}" as="commentaire">
               <span>{{commentaire.date}}</span>
           </template>
</tempalte>
```

I followed the Polymer Migration documentation but no results , i would be thankful if there is any solution .

Answer (score 5):

I think your comments property needs to be an array for it to bind correctly.

Comment: Well this is the real issue , i cannot manage this 'post.comments' even to convert it to array so i  have to use only but JavaScript to solve this problem. 
This is an issue related to the new migration from firebase-element(in 0.5 version of Polymer ) to the 1.0 .

Comment: You can write a filter like this `arrayify: function(obj) { return Object.keys(obj).map(function(k) { return obj[k]; }) }` and then bind to `items="{{arrayify(post.comments)}}"`.

Comment: @ScottMiles why not `Object.values(obj)` ?

Comment: @milan Not well [supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this without the 'as' tag.

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="{{posts}}">
      <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{item.comments}}">
           <span>{{item.date}}</span>
       </template>
</tempalte>
```

What i understand is 'items' is an internal term to polymer which represents an array/object. I might not be fully correct but this trick worked for me.